# Probability the $b$ is a cyclic vector of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices

Given a square, real matrix $A$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^N$ and a vector $b\in\mathbb{R}^N$, is the probability $1$ that $b$ is a cyclic vector of $A$ when (normalized, so a uniform distribution exists) $A$, $b$ are chosen uniformly randomly?

By a cyclic vector, I mean $\left\{A^nb \ \ | \ \ n \in \{0,\ldots, N\} \right\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: There is no uniform distribution on $\mathbb R^N$ or on $\mathbb R^{N\times N}$.

Comment: This is true. However, there is a uniform distribution on the set of normalised $A,b$. It doesn't make a difference to $b$ being a cyclic vector of $A$. So I will change the question to reflect this.

Comment: The Gaussian distribution should do.

Comment: Which matrix norm do you mean?

Comment: I think it likely won't matter? Let's say the Hilbet Schmidt inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should be yes. First, the probability is one that $A$ is chosen diagonalizable (over $\mathbb C$) with distinct eigenvalues $a_1,\ldots,a_N\in\mathbb C$. Hence, $[b,Ab,\ldots,A^{N-1}b] = S[c,Dc,\ldots,D^{N-1}c]$, where $c = S^{-1}b$. Now, the determinant of $[c,Dc,\ldots,D^{N-1}c]$ is the same as that of $VD_c$, where $V$ is the Vandermonde matrix generated by $a_1,\ldots,a_N$ and $D_c = \operatorname{diag}(c)$. Thus, the determinant is $c_1\ldots c_N\det(V)$, which is non-zero provided that none of the $c_j$'s is zero (which happens with probability zero). Of course this has to be made rigorous.

Comment: should that be $A^{N-1}b$ not $A^{N-1}n$? What is this $n$?

Comment: Of course, $b$. That letter is next to $n$ on the keyboard.

Comment: oh yes, so it is!